# JS Call back not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT 1:

Added to plug in settings:

```
'callbackModalOpen': null,
'callbackModalClose': null,
'callbackReset': null,
'jsonpCallback': null,
```

Added to plug in functions:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.mapDiv), myOptions);
$this.data('map', map);
    //Custom reset callback
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
       if (settings.callbackReset) {
           settings.callbackReset.call(this, orig_lat, orig_lng, map, infowindow);
       }
   });

//Create one infowindow to fill later
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

---

I am struggling with setting up a callback function to reset the map for jQuery Store Locator. My code:

```
jQuery('#map-container').storeLocator({
   callbackReset: function(orig_lat, orig_lng, map, infowindow){
      var originLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(orig_lat, orig_lng);
      map.panTo(originLatLng); //Center the map
      $('#loc-list li').removeClass('list-focus'); //Remove list focus
      infowindow.close(); //Close infowindow
   }
});
```

In the plug in code I have declared:

```
'callbackReset': null,
```

and

```
//Custom reset callback
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    if(settings.callbackReset){
          settings.callbackReset.call(this, orig_lat, orig_lng, map, infowindow);
     }
});
```

I am calling it like this: 
jQuery('#map-container').storeLocator('callbackReset' : true);

No errors in inspect, but not working. What am I doing wrong in my declaration of the function? I am wanting to be able to call this reset external to the plug in, how do I achieve this. Thanks

Comment: please share the plugin code

Comment: Hi Arun P Johnny, I just tried to place the code in my post but it is too much text and it will not let me save it. It comes from http://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin. Thanks

Comment: where are you adding the custom reset callback exactly?

Comment: Hi, see my post above.I think I am doing it right, but result is not as expected (nor it is failing with an error).

Comment: Try to break the code here to check the callbackReset value `if(settings.callbackReset)`

Comment: You have a typo in this line : `jQuery('#map-container').storeLocator('callbackReset);`

Comment: Yes,sorry but typo only on posting, not in code. I have fixed. Thanks